# How to break a long label of a trick into multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I make use of plot.ly for showing graphs to my users. But the labels of the X-axis are too long. What happens is that the label of the last bar is outside the graph and not visible. Therefore I want to break them in multiple lines so that it can be read more easily.Is there any way to this with plot.ly configuration or so?

Current graph with long labels on x-axis:

[image: current graph with long labels on x-axis]

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the traces into a function that can do the wrapping for you, since I am unable to find a plotlyish solution, I am providing this alternative, basically, I access the `x` property of each trace and then add `<br>` using regex, please check the below example and let me know if you have any doubts or issues.

```js
var trace1 = {
 x: [
  "this is a very long title that needs to be wrapped up for readability purposes2",
  "this is a very long title that needs to be wrapped up for readability purposes2",
  "this is a very long title that needs to be wrapped up for readability purposes3"
 ],
 y: [90, 40, 60],
 type: "bar",
 name: "New York Zoo"
};

var trace2 = {
 x: [
  "this is a very long title that needs to be wrapped up for readability purposes",
  "this is a very long title that needs to be wrapped up for readability purposes2",
  "this is a very long title that needs to be wrapped up for readability purposes3"
 ],
 y: [10, 80, 45],
 type: "bar",
 name: "San Francisco Zoo"
};
addBreaksAtLength = 10;
textwrapper = function(traces) {
 for (trace of traces) {
  trace.x = trace.x.map(text => {
   let rxp = new RegExp(".{1," + addBreaksAtLength + "}", "g");
   return text.match(rxp).join("<br>");
  });
 }
 return traces;
};
var data = textwrapper([trace1, trace2]);
var layout = {
 title: "Hide the Modebar",
 showlegend: true
};
Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout, { displayModeBar: false });
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;"></div>
```